# If there must be at least one person in each table, in how many ways can 6 people be seated in 3 tables?

Tags: combinatorics

> If there must be at least one person in each table, in how many ways can 6 people be seated in 3 tables?

I know there are three possible ways to split the set of people P into three distinct groups ($1+1+4,1+2+3,2+2+2$). Consider only the case $2+2+2$. At first I thought that the number of ways to choose the first pair of people to sit on a table is ${6\choose2}$ but for some reason it is $\frac{1}{3}\times {6\choose2}$. Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: Are the tables distinguishable, or are they identical?  Are they round tables?

Comment: I am sorry, I dont understand the first question. For the second question, altough not stated explicitly, i assume that the tables are round, because while looking at the answer, the author uses the circular permutation formula to figure out the number of ways a specific group can sit on the table, altough I cant see why that would matter in terms of the formula I would use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  By the first question, I mean does the author consider the tables identical, or are they labeled in some way?

Comment: They are identical. It does not matter if one group sits on one table or the other.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider the 3 cases mentioned above:

1) If they are split 4/1/1, there are $\dbinom{6}{4}$ ways to select the 4 people sitting together, and $3!$ ways to arrange them at their table, so this gives $\dbinom{6}{4}(3!)=15(6)=90$ possibilities.

2) If they are split 3/2/1, there are $\dbinom{6}{3}$ ways to select the 3 people sitting together, $2!$ ways to arrange them at their table, and $\dbinom{3}{2}$ ways to select the 2 people sitting together, so this gives $\hspace{.2 in}\dbinom{6}{3}\cdot2\cdot\dbinom{3}{2}=20(2)(3)=120$ possibilities.

3) If they are split 2/2/2, then there are $\displaystyle\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}}{3!}$ or $\;5\cdot3\cdot1=15$ ways to pair up the 6 people.

Therefore there are a total of $90+120+15=$225 possible ways to do this.

---

This is s(6,3), a Stirling number of the first kind.

Comment: In 1) don't you mean 1/1/4 and in 3) why is 3! in the denominator?

Comment: Yes, I did mean 1/1/4 - thanks.  In 3), since the tables are identical, we have to divide by the number of ways of numbering the tables.  (Another way to look at it is that we are just pairing up the 6 people, so the first person has 5 choices for a partner, then any remaining person has 3 choices for a partner, and one of the last 2 people has 1 choice for a partner.)

Comment: Isn't it a Stirling number of the *second* kind? [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), "Stirling numbers of the second kind count the number of ways to partition a set of n elements into k nonempty subsets".

Comment: @firegurafiku The (unsigned) Stirling numbers of the first kind $s(n,k)$ count the number of permutations of n elements with k disjoint cycles, and here we are counting the number of permutations of 6 elements that have 3 cycles.

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom 62$ ways of choosing 2 out of 6 people. Why do you think It should be multiplied by $\frac 13$?

Comment: Because that is the answer in the book I saw this in. It may be a mistake by the author of course...

Comment: Are you sure that he definitely means choosing a pair (2 people) ot ouf all 6 people? Without having them grouped into pairs before, say.

Comment: By the way it may have something to do with the fact that the groups have equal elements. Consider the case when you have to choose 2 groups with 3 people each. The number of ways to do so would be $\frac{1}{2} {6\choose 3}$

Comment: Yes I am sure..

Comment: But this doesn't apply here, since "going first" is not equal to "not going first". Strange. What's his overall result by the way?

Comment: I agree with you. The final result is $\frac{1}{3!}\times{6\choose 2}\times {4\choose2}\times 1!\times1!\times1!$ = $\frac{1}{3}\times{6\choose 2}\times \frac{1}{2} {4\choose2}\times 1!\times1!\times1! = 15$

Comment: 15 ways of seating those 6 people? The number should be far higher. Consider only the case $1+1+4$. There are $\binom 62$ ways of grouping 6 people into $1+1+4$. Now we have 6 ways of seating our 3 groups, which leads to 90 possible solutions. Plus the remaining cases $1+2+3$ and $2+2+2$ ...

Comment: I am sorry I thought you were asking for the number of ways of grouping only the group 2+2+2. The total is 225. (that is the answer in the book).

Comment: 15 is still far too low. For the case $2+2+2$, we have $\binom 62 * \binom 42$ options, which is again 90, right?

Comment: Well once you have chosen the first two people there are 4 left. The number of two pair combinations then is $\frac{1}{2} {4\choose 2}$, or in other words I personally think that the answer is ${6\choose2}\times \frac{1}{2}\times {4\choose 2} \times 1!\times 1!\times 1!$ . Since no one has answered this question in about an hour now I believe this is an author's mistake. +1 for your effort.

Comment: Haha, you're right of course, I forgot the factor $\frac 12$. Then we have 45, which is still far away from 15. I think you shouldn't trust the author's calculation. :)