# When do we need to account for permutations?

Tags: combinatorics

I was solving the following 2 problems:

> Let A be a 2n-element set where n≥1. Find the number of different
> pairings of A.

and

> If there must be at least one person in each table, in how many ways can 6 people be seated in 3 tables? Assuming that the tables are indistinguishable.

I know that for the first, the number of pairings is
$\frac{1}{n!}\binom{2n}{2}\binom{2n - 2}{2}\binom{2n - 4}{2} \cdots \binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}\\$. If my understanding is correct, what we are doing is picking pairs, and the picking pairs from the remaining number. The reason we divide by n! is because we we don't care about the order of the pairs. The formula above without the n! gives us the permutations of pairs.

What I don't understand is why we don't apply that same logic to the second problem.

We can split the problem up into these distinct groups: (1/1/4,1/2/3,2/2/2).

For the second group (1/2/3), the correct answer is: $\hspace{.2 in}\dbinom{6}{3}\cdot2\cdot\dbinom{3}{2}=20(2)(3)=120$

I don't understand why we don't need to divide this by something. I understand that the groups aren't identical in the same way the pairs in problem 1 were identical, but I don't see why that matters.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the difference between indistinguishability and distinguishability.

In the first example problem, imagine just for a moment that the pairs are labelled #1, #2, #3, etc. In other words, the pairs would be "distinguishable" and that "order does matter." So for a set like $\lbrace A,B,C,D\rbrace$, we could have that pair #1 is $\lbrace A,B\rbrace$ and pair #2 is $\lbrace C,D\rbrace$, which would be counted differently from if pair #1 was $\lbrace C,D\rbrace$ and pair #2 is $\lbrace A,B\rbrace$. But from the problem statement it is clear that this **isn't what we want**, but instead we want the pairs to be "**indistinguishable**" and that "order does not matter." So the example I showed previously would be counted as one and the same, $\lbrace A,B\rbrace$ and $\lbrace C,D\rbrace$. This is why the division by $n!$ is needed, to account for this indistinguishability among how the pairs are ordered.

But in the second example problem, it is to be assumed  that the tables are **distinguishable** in that you can tell apart which table is which. That allows you to label the tables #1, #2, and #3, whereas in the previous example problem, we could not do so. That means that we **do not need to divide by** $3!$ as with the other example problem, because the **order does matter** here. You could have $1$ person at table #1, $2$ people at table #2, and $3$ people at table #3, and that would be counted differently than $2$ people at table 1, $1$ person at table #2, and $3$ people at table #3. Note that if you divided by $3!$ here, these scenarios would be counted as one and the same, which is clearly not what you want. Also further note that **if the tables were indistinguishable**, then you actually would divide by $3!$ here, with a similar reasoning to the first example problem; the two scenarios I mentioned earlier in the paragraph would actually need to be counted the same as there wouldn't be a table #1, #2, and #3 anymore.

I probably didn't explain this the best, but I hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: I think I understand your point. The problem statement does however mention that "we assume that the tables are indistinguishable." I will edit my post to reflect that.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Hmm, I will have to look at the problem and your given solution more closely. You are sure that is the solution you pulled from a solutions manual or similar?

Comment: so there is an ordering to the tables t1 t2 t3 and there are an ordering for the table with 3 people, amongst how the 3 people are sitting, and for the table with 2 people, amongst how the 2 people are sitting. So for those two properties for problem #2 which are distinguishable and indistinguishable? I guess that is determined uniquely by the answer being 120 lol and I could have figured out what you were implying on my own. But instead I'll post this comment XD

Comment: nvm I think the OP just edited his original post. Tables are distinguishable, meaning the ordering of the tables physically? Or the ordering amongst people at any given table are distinguishable? I'm still confused about it actually but I guess I should have posted this on his question not your answer my bad.

Comment: The full solution is available here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248388/if-there-must-be-at-least-one-person-in-each-table-in-how-many-ways-can-6-peopl 
It is the same as the one in the book. 
@AidenChow

Comment: @Snared
The exact problem statement is 
If there must be at least one person in each table, in how many ways can 6 people be seated around three tables? (We assume that the tables are indistinguishable.)

Comment: @ChrisJohnson This clarifies things up. It looks like the **seats** are distinguishable, **not the tables**.

Comment: @Snared OP just gave a link that clarified the problem.

Comment: @AidenChow Is the reasoning you provided correct?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson With your clarification, I think that the problems are a bit too different to compare them side-by-side, but the core reasoning of my answer is accurate. The division by $n!$ only occurs when there is **indistinguishability**, as you would need to remove the extraneous orderings from being counted as different. The distinguishability from the second problem does not appear in the first problem, which is why the division by $n!$ is needed in the first problem but not the second.

Comment: But also note that in the 2/2/2 case, the solution you linked **does divide by** $3!$ and this is precisely because of the difference between **distinguishability** and **indistinguishability** that I mentioned. In this case, because each table will now have 2 people, the table assignments counted by $\binom62\binom42\binom22$ can now overlap with one another, which you will need to "divide out" because the tables are **indistinguishable**. If the tables are **dinstinguishable**, this division by $3!$ won't be necessary at all (though the other cases would most likely change as well).

Comment: I think the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/84413/user84413) provided by the answerer of your linked post provides a good explanation of why the division by $3!$ is necessary.

Comment: @AidenChow I feel like I'm closer to understanding. I understand why we need to divide by 3! in the 2/2/2 case. In the 1/2/3 case though, suppose the people were given by the letters {a,b,c,d,e,f}. Wouldn't ({a},{b,c,d,e},{f}) be the same as ({b,c,d,e},{a},{f}) and all other permutations? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson The division by $3!$ is not necessary in the 1/2/3 case because you can think about it this way; it has already been "decided" which table has 3 people, which table has 2, and which table has 1. Pretend just for a moment that we introduced the labels back onto the tables. We now decide beforehand that table #1 has 3 people, table #2 has 2, and #1 has 1. (1/2)

Comment: Then we do the counting as shown in the problem, being sure to account for the fact that the number of people in each table is already pre-chosen. Now after arranging the people in a certain way, we then remove the labels. This then accounts for the indistinguishability of the tables by already assuming one of the "orderings" of the tables. If you think about what dividing by $n!$ does, it is just removing out every other ordering so that there is only one left. With the assumption I mentioned in my previous comment, we implicitly already removed all orderings except the one we assumed. (2/2)

Comment: You can also assume, for example, that table #1 has 3 people, table #2 has 1 person, and table #3 has 2 people, do the exact same calculations, and then remove the labels, and see that it doesn't change anything. Even though we changed the assumption at the beginning, it is still only one such "ordering" out of all possible $n!$ orderings.

Comment: @AidenChow But can't you do the same thing (implicit pre-chosen technique) for the first problem? Like when you do $\hspace{.2 in}\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{1}{1}$ aren't you essentially doing the same thing as in the first problem. Isn't it just a permutation?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson This is because when you do $\binom{2n}2\binom{2n-2}2\cdots\binom22$ in the first problem, some of the cases **overlap** with each other even with the assumption I introduced earlier, which requires a division of $n!$ to fix. But because, for example, a table with $1$ person obviously can't have $2$ people sitting in it, **none of the cases overlap** when we do $\binom63\binom32$ and therefore we **do not need to divide by** $3!$.